# HTML Form Output and Validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I added the onclickevent to the button, but it still doesn't output my form correctly.

Comment: Remove the `onclick` from the button, then use `detailsForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); processForm(); });` (the problem is that clicking the button will run the JS code but then also submit the form. Since the form has no `action` attribute, this will effectively reload the page)

Answer (score 0):

By default, buttons inside a form have a type of `submit`, which means that the button will automatically submit the form when clicked.

To fix, the quickest way would be to add a `type="button"` property to your button:

```js
function clearErrors() {

  document.getElementById("firstnameError").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("lastnameError").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("usernameError").innerHTML = "";

}

function processForm() {

  clearErrors();

  var output = "";

  if (document.getElementById("firstname").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("firstnameError").innerHTML = "First name required";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("lastname").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("lastnameError").innerHTML = "Last name required";
  }



  output += "The form would submit the following information:"
  output += "\nFirst name: " + document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  output += "\nLast name: " + document.getElementById("lastname").value;


  if (document.getElementById("male").checked == true) {
    output += "\nSex: Male";
  } else {
    output += "\nSex: Female";
  }

  if (document.getElementById("car").checked == true) {
    output += "\nI have a car";
  }

  var education = document.getElementById("education");
  output += "\nEducation: " + education.options[education.selectedIndex].text;

  document.getElementById("output").value = output;

}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>HTML Forms</h1>
</div>

<div id="content">

  <form id="detailsForm">

    <p>

      First name&#58;<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />* <span id="firstnameError"></span><br /> Last name&#58;<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />* <span id="lastnameError"></span><br /> Username&#58;
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />* <span id="usernameError"></span><br /> Male <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="male" /> Female<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="female" checked /> <br /> I have a
      car&#58;<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" id="car" /><br /> Select a Level of Education&#58;<br />
      <select name="education" id="education">
        <option value="Secondary School">Secondary School</option>
        <option value="University">University</option>
      </select> <br />

      <button type="button" onclick="processForm()">Click me</button>


    </p>

    <p>
      <textarea name="output" id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
    </p>

  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your code as a snippet. It's working fine.

(Modified your code to have the `eventListener()` added in JS and not in HTML.)

```js
function clearErrors() {
  document.getElementById("firstnameError").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("lastnameError").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("usernameError").innerHTML = "";
}

function processForm() {

  clearErrors();

  var output = "";

  if (document.getElementById("firstname").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("firstnameError").innerHTML = "First name required";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("lastname").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("lastnameError").innerHTML = "Last name required";
  }

  output += "The form would submit the following information:"
  output += "\nFirst name: " + document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  output += "\nLast name: " + document.getElementById("lastname").value;

  if (document.getElementById("male").checked == true) {
    output += "\nSex: Male";
  } else {
    output += "\nSex: Female";
  }

  if (document.getElementById("car").checked == true) {
    output += "\nI have a car";
  }

  var education = document.getElementById("education");
  output += "\nEducation: " + education.options[education.selectedIndex].text;

  document.getElementById("output").value = output;

}

var btnSubmit = document.getElementById('btnSubmit')

btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  processForm()
})
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>HTML Forms</h1>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <form id="detailsForm">
    <p>
      First name&#58;<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />* <span id="firstnameError"></span><br /> Last name&#58;<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />* <span id="lastnameError"></span><br /> Username&#58;
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />* <span id="usernameError"></span><br /> Male <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="male" /> Female<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="female" checked /> <br /> I have a
      car&#58;
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" id="car" /><br /> Select a Level of Education&#58;<br />
      <select name="education" id="education">
        <option value="Secondary School">Secondary School</option>
        <option value="University">University</option>
      </select> <br />

      <button id="btnSubmit">Click me</button>


    </p>

    <p>
      <textarea name="output" id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
    </p>

  </form>

</div>
```